# How to center Label vertical and horizontal in draw2d Figure?

Tags: java, layout, figure, draw2d

I have the following situation:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("bla");
RoundedRectangle fig = new RoundedRectangle();
fig.add(label);
FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();
layout.setStretchMinorAxis(true);
fig.setLayoutManager(layout);
fig.setOpaque(true);
```

That works only to center the label vertical or horizontal by using layout.setHorizontal(true/false); , but not together. Any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setText("bla");
label.setTextAlignment(PositionConstants.CENTER);

RoundedRectangle fig = new RoundedRectangle();    
fig.setLayoutManager(new BorderLayout());
fig.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem to centralize label names using Simon's answers. Thx

```
setLayoutManager(new BorderLayout());
labelName.setTextAlignment(PositionConstants.CENTER);
add(labelName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.lightBlue);
```